# change global variable with click event

Tags: javascript, global-variables, addeventlistener, mouseclick-event

I am trying to change a global variable with a click event and I'm stuck.  I've tried it in the way the code is written below, and I'm getting the correct result in the console, but it's not working globally.  How else can I do it?

```js
    const levels = {
      easy: 5,
      medium: 3,
      hard: 2
    }
        
    let currentLevel = levels.hard
    
    document.querySelector('#easyBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
      currentLevel = levels.easy
      console.log (currentLevel)
    })
```

```html
<button id="easyBtn" type="button">Easy</button>
```

**Full Code:**

```js
window.addEventListener('load', init);

// Globals
const levels = {
  easy: 5,
  medium: 3,
  hard: 2
}


let currentLevel = levels.hard

    
document.querySelector('#easyBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
  currentLevel = levels.easy
  console.log (currentLevel)
})

document.querySelector('#mediumBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  currentLevel = levels.medium
  console.log (currentLevel)
})

document.querySelector('#hardBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  currentLevel = levels.hard
  console.log (currentLevel)
})

let time = currentLevel;
let score = 0;
let isPlaying;

// DOM Elemennts
const wordInput = document.querySelector('#word-input');
const currentWord = document.querySelector('#current-word');
const scoreDisplay = document.querySelector('#score');
const timeDisplay = document.querySelector('#time');
const message = document.querySelector('#message');
const seconds = document.querySelector('#seconds');

const words = [
  'hat',
  'river',
  'fun',
  'billion',
  'park',
  'superman',
  'quacky',
  'juggler',
  'word',
  'race',
  'bullet',
  'computer',
  'Anne',
  'Jacob',
  'Drew',
  'garden',
  'bike',
  'waffle',
  'hero',
  'statue',
  'loom',
  'backpack',
  'picture',
  'stand',
  'window',
  'marker',
  'bank',
  'chord',
  'lettuce',
  'color'
];

//Initialize game
function init() {
  
  seconds.innerHTML = currentLevel;
  //load word from array
  showWord(words);
  //start matching on word input
  wordInput.addEventListener('input', startMatch)
  //call countdown every second
  setInterval(countdown, 1000);
  //check game status
  setInterval(checStatus, 50);
}

//start match
function startMatch() {
  if(matchWords()) {
    isPlaying = true;
    time = currentLevel + 1;
    showWord(words);
    wordInput.value = '';
    score++;
  }

  //score is -1 display 0
  if(score === -1) {
    scoreDisplay.innerHTML = 0;
  } else {
    scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score;
  }
}

//match current word to wordInput
function matchWords() {
    if(wordInput.value === currentWord.innerHTML) {
      message.innerHTML = 'Correct!!!'
      return true;
    } else {
      message.innerHTML = '';
      return false;
    }
  }


function showWord(words) {
  // Generate random array index
  const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
  // Output random word
  currentWord.innerHTML = words[randIndex];
}

function countdown() {
  //make sure time is not run out
  if(time > 0) {
    time--;
  }else if(time === 0) {
      isPaying = false;
    }
    timeDisplay.innerHTML = time;
  }

  function checStatus() {
    if (!isPlaying === false && time === 0) {
      message.innerHTML = 'Game Over!!!';
      score = -1;
    }
  }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body {
  background-color: #a8a8a8;
}

.header {
  background-color: #4646c7;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height:  70px;
  align-items: center;
}

.btnSpacing {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: center;
  width: 100;
}

#easyBtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  
}

#mediumBtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#hardBtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#seconds {
  color: rgba(248, 2, 2, 0.753);
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Word Race</title>
</head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body class="body">
  <header class="header">
    <h1>Word Race</h1>
  </header>
  <br>
  <div class="container text-center col-md-6 mx-auto ">
      <!-- Buttons -->
      <div class="btnSpacing">
          <div>
            <button id="easyBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Easy</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button id="mediumBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Medium</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button id="hardBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Hard</button>
          </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>

    <!-- Word & Input -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <p class="lead">Type The Given Word Within
          <span  id="seconds">5</span> Seconds:</p>
        <h2 class="display-2 mb-5" id="current-word">hello</h2>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Start typing..." id="word-input" autofocus>
        <h4 class="mt-3" id="message"></h4>

  

        <!-- Time & Score Columns -->
        <div class="row mt-5">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Time Left:
              <span id="time">0</span>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Score:
              <span id="score">0</span>
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Instructions -->
        <div class="row mt-5">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card card-body bg-secondary text-white">
              <h5>Instructions</h5>
              <p>Type each word in the given amount of seconds to score. To play again, just type the current word. Your score
                will reset.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code you are mainly pointing out isn't attempting to change the variable, only access it.

Comment: How do I change it?

Comment: `levels.easy = someNewValue` With an assignment, it's always the thing on the left that is being assigned the value on the right.

Comment: I think he's asking why other stuff on the site doesn't update when the current level selected changes.

Comment: I'm trying to change the currentLevel value when a button is clicked.  How do I do that?

Comment: Also, please don't post your working code to 3rd party sites as those links can die over time. Just post it right here as a code snippet, which I have done via my edit for you.

Comment: Yes @SamVK you understand what I'm getting at

Comment: If you set a variable and use it, and then change the value of the variable, you have to look at the variable again to get the most recent value. It doesn't just update the UI automatically.

Comment: Thanks for the tips @ScottMarcus.  Are you able to show me a solution?

Answer (score 0):

What I take it you're asking is *"Why isn't stuff like the time given updating when I update the variable?"*

Javascript won't "listen" for changes on its own. After, you update the variable, you need to tell everything relying on it to also update.

There's a million different way to go about this (and a million libraries that try to *make* JavaScript essentially listen on changes). At the simplest level: you can try switching the currentLevel setting to a function, and have that also re-init the game.

```
setCurrentLevel(level) {
    currentLevel = levels.easy
    init()
    // any other stuff that needs to be updated/reset
}
// ...
document.querySelector('#easyBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
  setCurrentLevel(levels.easy)
})
```

```js
window.addEventListener('load', init);

// Globals
const levels = {
  easy: 5,
  medium: 3,
  hard: 2
}


let currentLevel = levels.hard

    
document.querySelector('#easyBtn').addEventListener('click', function () {
  setCurrentLevel(levels.easy)
})

document.querySelector('#mediumBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setCurrentLevel(levels.medium)
})

document.querySelector('#hardBtn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setCurrentLevel(levels.hard)
})

let time = currentLevel;
let score = 0;
let isPlaying;

// DOM Elemennts
const wordInput = document.querySelector('#word-input');
const currentWord = document.querySelector('#current-word');
const scoreDisplay = document.querySelector('#score');
const timeDisplay = document.querySelector('#time');
const message = document.querySelector('#message');
const seconds = document.querySelector('#seconds');

const words = [
  'hat',
  'river',
  'fun',
  'billion',
  'park',
  'superman',
  'quacky',
  'juggler',
  'word',
  'race',
  'bullet',
  'computer',
  'Anne',
  'Jacob',
  'Drew',
  'garden',
  'bike',
  'waffle',
  'hero',
  'statue',
  'loom',
  'backpack',
  'picture',
  'stand',
  'window',
  'marker',
  'bank',
  'chord',
  'lettuce',
  'color'
];

//Initialize game
function init() {
  
  seconds.innerHTML = currentLevel;
  //load word from array
  showWord(words);
  //start matching on word input
  wordInput.addEventListener('input', startMatch)
  //call countdown every second
  setInterval(countdown, 1000);
  //check game status
  setInterval(checStatus, 50);
}

//start match
function startMatch() {
  if(matchWords()) {
    isPlaying = true;
    time = currentLevel + 1;
    showWord(words);
    wordInput.value = '';
    score++;
  }

  //score is -1 display 0
  if(score === -1) {
    scoreDisplay.innerHTML = 0;
  } else {
    scoreDisplay.innerHTML = score;
  }
}

//match current word to wordInput
function matchWords() {
    if(wordInput.value === currentWord.innerHTML) {
      message.innerHTML = 'Correct!!!'
      return true;
    } else {
      message.innerHTML = '';
      return false;
    }
  }


function showWord(words) {
  // Generate random array index
  const randIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length);
  // Output random word
  currentWord.innerHTML = words[randIndex];
}

function countdown() {
  //make sure time is not run out
  if(time > 0) {
    time--;
  }else if(time === 0) {
      isPaying = false;
    }
    timeDisplay.innerHTML = time;
  }

  function checStatus() {
    if (!isPlaying === false && time === 0) {
      message.innerHTML = 'Game Over!!!';
      score = -1;
    }
  }
  
  function setCurrentLevel(level) {
    currentLevel = level;
    init();
  }
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.body {
  background-color: #a8a8a8;
}

.header {
  background-color: #4646c7;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height:  70px;
  align-items: center;
}

.btnSpacing {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-content: center;
  width: 100;
}

#easyBtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  
}

#mediumBtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#hardBtn {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#seconds {
  color: rgba(248, 2, 2, 0.753);
  font-weight: bold
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Word Race</title>
</head>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<body class="body">
  <header class="header">
    <h1>Word Race</h1>
  </header>
  <br>
  <div class="container text-center col-md-6 mx-auto ">
      <!-- Buttons -->
      <div class="btnSpacing">
          <div>
            <button id="easyBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-success">Easy</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button id="mediumBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-warning">Medium</button>
          </div>
          <div>
            <button id="hardBtn" type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Hard</button>
          </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>

    <!-- Word & Input -->
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
        <p class="lead">Type The Given Word Within
          <span  id="seconds">5</span> Seconds:</p>
        <h2 class="display-2 mb-5" id="current-word">hello</h2>
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Start typing..." id="word-input" autofocus>
        <h4 class="mt-3" id="message"></h4>

  

        <!-- Time & Score Columns -->
        <div class="row mt-5">
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Time Left:
              <span id="time">0</span>
            </h3>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6">
            <h3>Score:
              <span id="score">0</span>
            </h3>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Instructions -->
        <div class="row mt-5">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="card card-body bg-secondary text-white">
              <h5>Instructions</h5>
              <p>Type each word in the given amount of seconds to score. To play again, just type the current word. Your score
                will reset.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

---

***Edit:*** It looks like there may be some other function that may need to also be rewritten like when/how the actual countdown is set (or some general refactoring so they're called in init are there are fewer global variables) but this is the rough answer. You need to explicitly tell the game when settings have been updated and when to re-run.

Comment: That did it for me.  I appreciate the help.